# How to set initial state with undo action on React?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, drag-and-drop, setstate, react-big-calendar

I have a react-big-calendar with drag and drop, I want when I move an event to another position, a snackbar appeared which having the undo action like that  :

[image]

I want when I click on the undo action, the event set the initial state (the initial position)

My code is :

```
 moveEvent = ({event, start, end, isAllDay: droppedOnAllDaySlot}) => {
      const { events } = this.state;
      const idx = events.indexOf(event);
      let allDay = event.allDay ;
      if(!event.allDay && droppedOnAllDaySlot)
      {allDay = true;}
      else if (event.allDay && !droppedOnAllDaySlot)
      { allDay = false;}
      const updatedEvent = { ...event, start, end, allDay }
      const nextEvents = [...events]
      nextEvents.splice(idx, 1, updatedEvent)
      this.setState({
        events : nextEvents,
        dragAndDrop : true,
        open : true
      })
  }
  handleClose = () => {
      this.setState({ open: false });
  };
  handleClick = () => {
      this.setState({ open: true });
  };
  handleUndo = () => {
      this.setState({
        dragAndDrop : !this.state.dragAndDrop,
        events: this.state.events
      })
 }
  render() {
    return (
       <div>
          <DragAndDropCalendar
            selectable
            localizer={localizer}
            events={this.state.events} 
            views={['month','week','day']}
            //defaultDate={new Date(2019, 2, 19)}
            defaultView="week"
            culture = 'fr'
            timeslots={1}
            step={15}
            style={{ height: "100vh" }}
            onEventDrop={this.moveEvent}
            min={new Date(2017, 10, 0, 7, 0, 0)}
            max={new Date(2017, 10, 0, 21, 0, 0)} 
            resizable  
            onEventResize={this.resizeEvent}
            onSelectSlot={this.newEvent}
            onSelectEvent={this.handleClickOpen}
          />
        <Snackbar
          anchorOrigin={{
            vertical: 'bottom',
            horizontal: 'center',
          }}
          open={this.state.open}
          autoHideDuration={6000}
          onClose={this.handleClose}
          ContentProps={{
            'aria-describedby': 'message-id',
          }}
          message={<span id="message-id">Evénement enregistré</span>}
          action={[
              <Button key="undo" color="secondary" size="small" onClick={this.handleUndo}>
                Annuler
              </Button>,
              <IconButton
                key="close"
                aria-label="Close"
                color="inherit"
                onClick={this.handleClose}
              >
                <CloseIcon />
              </IconButton>,
            ]}
        />
```

My full code :  https://codesandbox.io/s/mq42x1j90x

When I run my code and I click on the undo action, it doesn't work,  and my event doesn't set the initial position.

How can I fix that ?

Comment: If you mean what you're doing in `handleUndo()`, then `events: this.state.events` is not doing anything, because you just assign the same value to itself. Besides what is the value of initial state? It's not in the codes you provided.

Comment: @MarsonMao, yes I want to cancel the drag and drop on the `handleUndo()`

Comment: also cancel the `events`, right?

Comment: Exactly @MarsonMao

Comment: So maybe you just do `events: []`?

Comment: Wait, or you just want to cancel the lastes 1 event?

Comment: I want when I dragAnDrop the event, the snackbar appeared and when I click on the undo button, the event will be moved to the older position like Calendar of Google

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I suggest to store previous events  in separate field inside this.state(for instance, **this.state.previousEvents)**, and at *undo()* action set current events to previous events. Also, when user closes snackbar or do some other action which changes events and can't be reverted, don't forget to update previousEvents as current events value.

Also instead of using *this.state* in *this.setState*

```
this.setState({
        dragAndDrop : !this.state.dragAndDrop,
        events: this.state.events
      })
```

you should use *previousState*:

```
this.setState((prevState) => ({
        dragAndDrop : !prevState.dragAndDrop,
        events: prevState.events
      }))
```

So the full version is

```
class Calendar extends Component {
  state  = {
    events: [],
    prevEvents: []
  };

  handleUndo = () => {
    this.setState((prevState) => ({
      events: prevState.prevEvents
    }))
  }

  handleCloseSnackbar = () => {
    this.setState((prevState) => ({
      prevEvents: prevState.events
    }))
  }

  ...
}
```

Comment: I get `Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'setState' of undefined` into `handleUndo()`

Comment: @CodeLover  that’s weird, but that was just a quick example and I could mistyped something. We can discuss it in chat or you can paste your code to sandbox

Comment: I edited your sandbox and it works, please check it https://codesandbox.io/s/kkm0okkr4o.

Comment: and what about when the events is getted from the database, and I initialise it on my state :`events :[]`

Comment: You can create a HOC(High-order-component), which will connect to store and get events from it. And pass events as prop to your calendar. Then, in calendar you can write constructor and initialize your state based on passed props. Here is the link to general code (it doesn't work, its just the idea of what you can do) https://pastebin.com/KMNVXHCJ

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/190915/discussion-between-codelover-and-ifsogirl).